# how to set a rule in Firebase that allows writing IF CHILD DOES NOT EXIST?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Unable to set a rule that allows writing to child "NEWS" if the resource does not exist.
(in the application I wrote a code that restores the "NEWS" child in Firebase if it does not exist)

I tried several actions that it makes no sense to bring below. The last was the following:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "NEWS":{
       ".read": "auth.uid!==null",         
       ".write": "auth.uid!==null &&
                 !data.parent().child('NEWS').exists()",  // ! doesn't work
}}}
```

JAVA: READ CHILD "NEWS"

```
REF_NEWS_FILM = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(KEY_CHILD_NEWS).child(KEY_LANGUAGE).child(KEY_CHILD_NEWS_ABOUT_nameOfFilm);
ValueEventListener vel_news = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {

            if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                String newsDefault = getResources().getString(R.string.no_news_yet);   // no news
                MyStringClass newsDefaultClass = new MyStringClass(newsDefault);
                REF_NEWS_FILM.push().setValue(newsDefaultClass);
                } else {
                Query queryNews = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(KEY_CHILD_NEWS).child(KEY_LANGUAGE).child(KEY_CHILD_NEWS_ABOUT_nameOfFilm).orderByChild("text");
            queryNews.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dss : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        MyStringClass newsClass = dss.getValue(MyStringClass.class);
                        assert newsClass != null;
                        String newsString = newsClass.getText();
                        TV_NEWS_ABOUT_FILM.setText(newsString);
                    }}
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw databaseError.toException();   // advice from Frank
                }});} 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw databaseError.toException();   // advice from Frank
    }};
REF_NEWS_FILM.addValueEventListener(vel_news);

}
```

Comment: Security rules only get meaning once they are exercised by code. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces the problem against these rules?

Comment: 1) Please don't ignore errors. At its minimum `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`, which will also allow you to see which of your operations is failing. 2) Since your rules require that `auth.uid!==null` to be allowed to read, ensure in your code that this condition is met by putting `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null` around the code you shared.

Comment: OK. Thank you Mr. Frank. I'll fix the code and post it again (for others)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `!data.exists()`:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "NEWS": {
            ".read": "auth.uid!==null",
            ".write": "auth.uid!==null && !data.exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

To prevent writing `null` to it, you should probably extend to also check that `newData.exists()`:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "NEWS": {
            ".read": "auth.uid!==null",
            ".write": "auth.uid!==null && newData.exists() && !data.exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. (Test in PlayGround shows ERROR)